# How do I separate an enchantment book with multiple enchantments?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I have been enchanting books in minecraft lately since I wanted *Looting* for my pickaxe and I finally enchanted a book and got it. I then realised I had *Silk Touch* on it as well.

How do I separate them since *Looting* won’t work if *Silk Touch* is also in the pickaxe?

Comment: Just FYI, looting applies to swords. The equivalent pickaxe enchantment is Fortune.

Comment: [Related, possible dupe](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/356190/73976)

Answer (score 4):

**Simple answer: You can't.**

You need to choose between the silk touch and looting, by either having a looting sword, or a silk touch tool. Without discarding the book and cheating for a looting book and cheating for a silk touch book, there is no way to do that in vanilla survival Minecraft. If you want a looting sword and a silk touch tool, you need to get a whole new book, or manually enchant the sword and pickaxe. See [Fastest way to get enchanted books?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/272380/fastest-way-to-get-enchanted-books).

Comment: Thanks I will now enchant all my pickaxes until I get looting

Comment: @Joe LOOTING APPLY'S TO SWORDS! FORTUNE APPLY'S TO PICKAXES

Comment: Looting APPLYS there's no contraction :)

Answer (score 2):

Looting doesn’t go on tools, it only goes on swords. You are looking for fortune, and you will never get a book with fortune and silk touch from an enchanting table.